# Speed up a C++ code solving a 1-d Schrödinger equation

Tags: c++, performance

In the following, you see my c++ code that it solves 1-d Schrödinger equation with [Numerov's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method). But I have two problems:

1. When I increase the size of the box, the wave function for the ground state will be zero, the problem is in Normalization and I do not know why.
2. It is too slow, I need to increase box sufficiently large, any idea about how to speed up would be great.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#define pi 3.1415926535897932384626433

class ID_TISE{

    public:
        ID_TISE(int N_graid, int x_min, int x_max, double dx, double e_tr, double de, double e_up, double m, double h_bar, double c);
        ~ID_TISE();

        //functions
        double Potential(char, int);
        double PotentialIon(char, int);
        void Setk2(double *k2, double E, int N, char lr);
        void Numerov(double *psi, double *k2, int N);
        double diff_slope(double e_tr,int N_L, int N_R);;
        string string_precision(int, int);
        double x(char lr, int index);
        void Numerov_Solver(double*, double*);
        void id_tise();

        int N_graid ;

        double x_min;
        double x_max;
        double dx;

        //set trial energy
        double e_tr;
        double de;
        double e_up;
        int N_E = 10000;

        //constant
        double m ;
        double h_bar;
        double c; // second point of the wavefunctions

        //array
        double *psi_l = NULL;
        double *psi_r = NULL;
        double *k2_l = NULL;
        double *k2_r = NULL;

};

ID_TISE::ID_TISE(int N_graid, int x_min, int x_max, double dx, double e_tr, double de, double e_up, double m, double h_bar, double c){

    this->N_graid = N_graid;
    this->x_min = x_min;
    this->x_max = x_max;
    this->dx = dx;
    this->e_tr =e_tr;
    this->de = de;
    this->e_up = e_up;
    this->m = m;
    this->h_bar=h_bar;
    this->c=c;

    psi_l = new double[N_graid];
    psi_r = new double[N_graid];
    k2_l = new double[N_graid];
    k2_r = new double[N_graid];

}

ID_TISE::~ID_TISE(){

    delete[] psi_l;
    delete[] psi_r;
    delete[] k2_l;
    delete[] k2_r;

}

void ID_TISE::id_tise(){

    ofstream fout;

    int im = int(N_graid/2);
    int N_R = N_graid - im + 2;
    int N_L = im + 2;

    //initialization left solution
    psi_l[0] = 0.0;
    psi_l[1] = c;
    //initialization right solution
    psi_r[0] = 0.0;
    psi_r[1] = c;

    int ii = 0, inode = 0, inodeUp = 1;
    while(e_tr < e_up){
        double ds1 = diff_slope(e_tr,N_L,N_R);
        e_tr += de;
        double ds2 = diff_slope(e_tr,N_L,N_R);

        if(ds1*ds2 < 0.0){

            if(e_tr < -9.0e-7 || e_tr > 9.0e-7){ // to prevent reaching to E = 0
                cout <<"E_"<<ii++ <<" = "<< e_tr << endl;
                Normalizer(psi_r,im);
                Normalizer(psi_l,im);

                fout.open("psi_"+string_precision(ii,0)+ ".dat");

                if(e_tr < 0){

                    if(inode%2 != 0.){
                            for(int i = 0; i < im; i++)
                                fout << x('l',i) << "\t" << -psi_l[i] << endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i = 0; i < im; i++)
                            fout << x('l',i) << "\t" << psi_l[i] << endl;
                    }
                    for(int i = im-1; i > -1; i--)
                        fout << x('r',i) << "\t" << psi_r[i] << endl;

                    inode++;
                }
                else{

                    if(inodeUp%2 == 0.){
                        for(int i = 0; i < im; i++)
                            fout << x('l',i) << "\t" << -psi_l[i] << endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        for(int i = 0; i < im; i++)
                            fout << x('l',i) << "\t" << psi_l[i] << endl;
                    }
                    for(int i = im-1; i > -1; i--)
                        fout << x('r',i) << "\t" << psi_r[i] << endl;

                    inodeUp++;

                }

                fout.close();
            }
        }
        else continue;
    }
}

void ID_TISE::Normalizer(double *psi,int N){

    double sum = 0.;

    for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++)
        sum += psi[i]*psi[i]*dx;

    sum=sqrt(sum);

    for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++){
        psi[i]=psi[i]/sum;
    }
}


void ID_TISE::Numerov(double *psi, double *k2 , int N){

    double h12 = (dx*dx)/12.;
    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++){
        psi[i+1] = (2.*(1.-5.*h12*k2[i])*psi[i] - (1. + h12*k2[i-1])*psi[i-1])/(1. + h12*k2[i+1]);
    }
}

void ID_TISE::Setk2(double *k2, double E, int N, char lr){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(E > 0)
            k2[i] = (2.*m/(h_bar*h_bar))*(E - PotentialIon(lr,i));
        else
            k2[i] = (2.*m/(h_bar*h_bar))*(E - Potential(lr,i));
    }
}

double ID_TISE::Potential(char lr, int index){
    return -1./sqrt(x(lr, index)*x(lr, index)+2.);
}

double ID_TISE::PotentialIon(char lr, int index){
    return 0.;
}

double ID_TISE::x(char lr, int index){
    if(lr == 'l')
        return x_min + (index)*dx; // dx = h
    else
        return x_max - (index)*dx; // the right solution
}

double ID_TISE::diff_slope(double e_tr, int N_L, int N_R){

    double dslope;
    //initialization left solution
    psi_l[0] = 0.0;
    psi_l[1] = c;
    //initialization right solution
    psi_r[0] = 0.0;
    psi_r[1] = c;
    Setk2(k2_l, e_tr, N_L, 'l');
    Setk2(k2_r, e_tr, N_R, 'r');
    Numerov(psi_l, k2_l, N_L);
    Numerov(psi_r, k2_r, N_R);
    double y_m = (psi_l[N_L-1]+psi_r[N_R-1])/2.;
    dslope = (2.*y_m - psi_l[N_L - 3] - psi_r[N_R - 3])/(dx*psi_r[N_R - 2]);

    return dslope;

}


string ID_TISE::string_precision(int value, int n_digits){

    if(n_digits < 6) n_digits = 6;
    ostringstream out;
    out << fixed<<setprecision(n_digits) << value;
    return out.str();
}


int main(){

    int N_graid = 500000;

    double x_min = -500;
    double x_max = -x_min;
    double dx = (x_max - x_min)/(N_graid-1);

    //set trial energy
    double e_tr = -0.6;
    double de = 0.000001;
    double e_up = 1.0;

    //constant
    double m = 1.;
    double h_bar = 1.;
    double c = 0.00000001; // second point of the wavefunctions
    ID_TISE &id_tise = *(new ID_TISE(N_graid,x_min,x_max,dx,e_tr,de,e_up,m,h_bar,c));
    id_tise.id_tise();


}
```

Comment: this is unreadable and more C than C++.
try first cleanup your code, give proper names and use C++ datastructures like std::vector or std::array.
your performance problem is most likeley in bad memory alignment of your data structures making some of the for loops quite slow

Comment: A lot of your code is unused (for example, `Numerov_Solver()` is never called). Please trim out the unused code so people looking to answer your question are less likely to be immediately turned off by the amount of code to sift through.

Comment: try to create a [mcve]. No one will read the whole code. And if the code works then it should be on [codereview.se]

Comment: @JaMiT yes some of the functions are unused, due to I use these functions in another code. any way you right

Comment: @skeller thank you for the reply. I don't think the problem is in using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of that I used, but I will try it, and let you know

Comment: @phuclv thanks I will do that.

Comment: `ID_TISE &id_tise = *(new ID_TISE(...))` why? This leaks memory. This is just `ID_TISE id_tise(....)`. Some of the function could be `static` or `constexpr` and variable could point to `const` locations.

Comment: @KamilCuk due to I use this class in part of another code and in that code I pass these constants

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to use this class in another code in that code I define `N_graid , .....` and remove the `main()` function in this code. Do you say it is not a good way? And what is the rule 3? Also, I have no problem with memory. my problem is when I increase  `x_min` the results tend to zero and If I don't normalize the data I will face with a large value of data

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sum += psi[i]*psi[i];`, without `*dx`, in the normalizer?

Comment: @Bob__ in Hilbert space we must have something like this `$\int \psi(x)^{*}\psi(x) = 1$`

Comment: Good point. Still, `dx` is a constant in your case, so you could sum the products and then multiply by `dx * N`. Instead of `x()` and `Potential()`, precalculate and store their values in some vectors (left and right side, as you did with psi and k2, to avoid the conditional on each value). Those values are indipendent of `E`. Do you really need 500000 steps of integration?

Comment: OK, next step is to act as a translator. You are using advanced non-computer terms to ask a question of computer folks. You might get a better response if you, for example, explained what "the wave function for the ground state will be zero" means in terms of values of variables (which variables are zero when they should be nonzero?). It might also help to present the observations that led you to believe the problem is in `Normalizer()`.